# How to extract data from Message and display it in Notification(Android)

Tags: notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I used GCM(Google Cloud Message) for push notification.

When Notification Arrived on Device It looks Like this :

```
Received: Bundle[{message=hello, android.support.content.wakelockid=2,
collapse_key=do_not_collapse, from=243316392621}]
```

Now I wanted to extract message and wakelockId in such a way that Only message displayed on notification.(In this example only hello)

Here my notificationBuider is as below :

```
  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(com.example.example.R.drawable.icon)
    .setContentTitle("Example")
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)     
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(msg))
    .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Please Guide me on this.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the notification you got, I'm assuming that `msg` is of type `Bundle` and its value is `intent.getExtras()` where `intent` is the `intent` of the GCM BroadcastReceiver.

You should extract the relevant parameter from it :

```
 String text = msg.getString ("message");
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(com.example.example.R.drawable.icon)
    .setContentTitle("Example")
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)     
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(text))
    .setContentText(text);

 mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
 mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Recibido: Bundle [{mensaje = hola, android.support.content.wakelockid = 2,
collapse_key = do_not_collapse, desde = 243316392621}]

In this way is that google send your data which you have defined in your application server you must do is read this data individually something like

extras.getString ("message")

where message is the data that has defined the key value of your server application